# Composite pattern with bidirectional association between Component and Composite

Tags: design-patterns, composite, bidirectional

I have the problem mentioned in title of this post. By default, Composite Pattern has explicit implementation of Composite -> Component association. But I also need to implement association in reverse direction : Component -> Composite.

[image]

In short, what is the best solution for bidirectional association between Component and Composite object in Composite Pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You only need an association between Component and itself, and call this "parent"

With this design, all leaf and composite will have a reference to his parent, this means Composite -> Component association

[image]

Comment: Can `Composite` interact with `Component`, modifying it or calling its method, or is it an anti-pattern solution?